# Why does the Python tag show me a Java question?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I just realized a question on Python tag shows me a Java question. It has no [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag only [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/loops). [Here's a screenshot of what I saw](http://2.1m.yt/3JU5AV.jpg)

Is this a bug or is there something that I don't know? This is the first time I've seen a question on the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag that only has Java code.

Comment: It probably had been tagged with python and recently edited. They remain in that tag for a short while after editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the post was originally created it was tagged with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) it was then retagged (twice) removing the javascript and then the python tags. The [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35704293/timeline) is useful in seeing what happened to a post.

When you ran the query it used some cached data in the where clause but returned updated data in the view.

Answer (score 4):

Caching.

The question used to have the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag on it. See [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35704293/2). It takes a while for caching to catch up with tag edits.